# Caching in Spring 5 WebFlux

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-webflux

Are there any way to cache a Flux coming from WebClient in Spring 5? I tried this but is not caching anything.

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class GatewayApplication {

 @PostMapping(value ="/test", produces = "application/json")
 public Flux<String> handleRequest(@RequestBody String body) {
    return getHspadQuery(body);
 }

 @Cacheable("testCache")
 private Flux<String> getData (String body) {
    return WebClient.create().post()
            .uri("http://myurl")
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
            .retrieve().bodyToFlux(String.class).cache();
 }
}
```

When I make the third request it never finishs. And in then in the subsequent requests I get the response but the server throws the following:

```
2018-04-09 12:36:23.920 ERROR 11488 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] r.ipc.netty.channel.ChannelOperations    : [HttpServer] Error processing connection. Requesting close the channel
reactor.core.Exceptions$OverflowException: Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests
at reactor.core.Exceptions.failWithOverflow(Exceptions.java:215) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.emit(FluxBufferPredicate.java:292) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onNextNewBuffer(FluxBufferPredicate.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.tryOnNext(FluxBufferPredicate.java:205) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxBufferPredicate$BufferPredicateSubscriber.onNext(FluxBufferPredicate.java:180) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:646) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:523) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:897) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:128) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:6873) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:372) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:108) ~[reactor-core-3.1.5.RELEASE.jar:3.1.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:211) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
at reactor.ipc.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:326) ~[reactor-netty-0.7.5.RELEASE.jar:0.7.5.RELEASE]
...
```

And it never caches anything.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it with Mono. I guess is possible with Flux for example using a reduce.

```
@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

@Autowired
CacheManager manager;


private WebClient client;

@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
    client = WebClient.builder()
            .baseUrl("http://myurl")
            .exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies.withDefaults())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(Arrays.asList(new ConcurrentMapCache("hspad")));
    return cacheManager;
}

@PostMapping(value = "/hspad/grahql", produces = "application/json")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> hspadService(@RequestBody String body) {
    return getHspadQuery(body);
}

private Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> getHspadQuery (String body) {
    Mono<ResponseEntity<String>> mono;
    Optional<Cache.ValueWrapper> value = Optional.ofNullable(cacheManager().getCache("hspad").get(body));

    if(value.isPresent()) {
        mono = Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(value.get().get().toString()));
    } else {
        mono = client.post()
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(body))
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).map(response ->
                {
        // Care blocking operation! (use cacheManager -not found yet- prepared for reactive)                        cacheManager().getCache("hspad").putIfAbsent(body,response);
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
                });
    }
    return mono;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

Comment: `cacheManager().getCache("hspad").putIfAbsent(body,response);` looks like a blocking operation to me - you're likely to run into big scalability issues doing that

Comment: Thaks Brian, how would you face it? Caching is not already integrated with Spring 5 Reactor.

Comment: We'd need proper caching support from the CacheManager API first; for that, we'd also need reactive support from caching implementations (are you using one right now?). See also https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14235

Answer (score 9):

There is an reactor [cache add-on](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/tree/master/reactor-extra/src/main/java/reactor/cache) which can be used with Spring CacheManager.
But, as pointed out by the comments in the accepted answer, currently, the Spring cache APIs(gets and puts) are still blocking. We can only make the program fully reactive until this issue is solved.

Here is the sample code snippet in java.
The complete sample project is [here](https://github.com/chang-chao/reactive-cats) in github.

```
@Service
public class CatServiceImpl implements CatService {
    private static final String CACHE_NAME = "sr";
    private static final String KEY = "k";
    @Autowired
    private WebClient client;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Function<String, Mono<List<Signal<CatDto>>>> reader = k -> Mono
            .justOrEmpty((Optional.ofNullable((List<CatDto>) (cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME).get(k, List.class)))))
            .flatMap(v -> Flux.fromIterable(v).materialize().collectList());

    private BiFunction<String, List<Signal<CatDto>>, Mono<Void>> writer = (k, sigs) -> Flux.fromIterable(sigs)
            .dematerialize().collectList().doOnNext(l -> cacheManager.getCache(CACHE_NAME).put(k, l)).then();

    @Override
    public Flux<CatDto> search() {
        Flux<CatDto> fromServer = client.get().retrieve().bodyToFlux(CatDto.class);

        return CacheFlux.lookup(reader, KEY).onCacheMissResume(fromServer).andWriteWith(writer);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For now, `@Cacheable` doesn't work with `Flux` (and Reactor in general).
But regarding your example, each time you call the method, you're creating a new `Flux` instance, so naturally, it never caches anything.

To be able to cache results, you need to either convert a `Flux` to a list instance, or simply keep reusing one `Flux` instance

Comment: Thanks and do you know why the "Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests" error? Keep getting this error even without cache.

Comment: @EstebanS to be able to answer that I'd need to see the server-side code

Answer (score 0):

I made an alternative way that annotation & aop based spring reactor cache using [reactor cache add-on](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/tree/master/reactor-extra/src/main/java/reactor/cache) until spring framework's @Cacheable annotation supports reactive cache.

https://github.com/pkgonan/reactor-cache

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface MonoCacheable {

    String value() default "";

}

abstract class AbstractSpringCache<T> {

    protected Cache cache;
    protected Class<T> type;

    protected AbstractSpringCache(Cache cache, Class<T> type) {
        this.cache = cache;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public class SpringMonoCache<T> extends AbstractSpringCache<T> implements MonoCache<T> {

    public SpringMonoCache(Cache cache, Class<T> type) {
        super(cache, type);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<T> find(Mono<T> retriever, String key) {
        return CacheMono.lookup(reader, key)
                .onCacheMissResume(retriever)
                .andWriteWith(writer);
    }

    /** Mono Cache reader function **/
    private Function<String, Mono<Signal<? extends T>>> reader = k -> Mono
            .fromCallable(() -> cache.get(k, type))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .flatMap(t -> Mono.justOrEmpty(Signal.next(t)));

    /** Mono Cache writer function **/
    private BiFunction<String, Signal<? extends T>, Mono<Void>> writer = (k, signal) -> Mono
            .fromRunnable(() -> Optional.ofNullable(signal.get())
                    .ifPresent(o -> cache.put(k, o)))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
            .then();
}

@Aspect
@Component
class ReactorAnnotationCacheAspect {

    ...

    @Around("annotationOfAnyMonoCacheable() && " +
            "executionOfAnyPublicMonoMethod()")
    final Object around(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        ...

        try {
            return reactorCacheAspectSupport.execute(aspectJInvoker, method, args);
        } catch(...) {}...

        return joinPoint.proceed(args);
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(reactor.cache.spring.annotation.MonoCacheable)")
    private void annotationOfAnyMonoCacheable() {}

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(public reactor.core.publisher.Mono *(..))")
    private void executionOfAnyPublicMonoMethod() {}
}


class ReactorCacheAspectSupport {

    private final CacheManager cacheManager;
    ...

    Object execute(final CacheOperationInvoker invoker, final Method method, final Object[] args) {
        ...
        return execute(cache, invoker.invoke(), key, returnType);
    }

    private Object execute(final Cache cache, final Object proceed, final String key, final Class<?> type) {
        ...
        final ReactorCache cacheResolver = getCacheResolver(cache, type);
        return cacheResolver.find(proceed, key);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: umm.. I didn't know that and i added source code about that.