# jhipster omits configuration options when choosing to make application reactive with Spring WebFlux

Tags: jhipster

I've noticed that when i create a new jhipster app using the jhipster-generator i'm not able to configure Websockets using Spring Websocket, Hibernate 2nd level Caching or Spring caching when i answer the question `Do you want to make it reactive with Spring WebFlux?` with Yes.

My question is: Why is this so? Why doesn't the jhipster-generator allow me to add Websockets and caching to my app while at the same time making it reactive using Spring WebFlux?

Comment: I don't know specifically for your issue, but usually it means that some options are incompatible either due to a bug in a dependency or they will never be compatible. I suggest that you ask this question on github. It's also possible that this has been fixed in next release 8.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSocket with WebFlux is not implemented. See https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/16942 for more information.

Spring's `@Cacheable` is blocking, so it's not implemented for WebFlux. Learn more at [Caching in Spring 5 WebFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49731127/caching-in-spring-5-webflux).